# Are there pretrained models on the ImageNet Bounding Boxes dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition, cnn

When searching for some pretrained models for object detection with bounding boxes, I was wondering if there are also pretrained models on the ImageNet dataset for bounding boxes. Most of the time, I find models trained on the VOC or COCO dataset. Is there a reason for this? I'd like to have a model that is pretrained on many categories. If I saw correctly, the ImageNet dataset is much richer than the VOC or COCO dataset.

Comment: Same question! Have you found a pretrained model??? Thanks!

Comment: I personally feel, as all of us here are still learning here about how to even implement such a network to train our own models. All of us here who stumble upto such a question can get a good answer, only on contacting the authors of the NN who have chosen to use VOC and COCO rather than ImageNet.